# VS 2013 RC and TFS 2012 Exception - TFS API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

i get this error "Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationHost' to type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer'.", when i try to get the ITeamExplorer service from a vspackage.

Here is the code:

```
ITeamExplorer _teamExplorer = (ITeamExplorer)_currentVsPackage.GetBaseService(typeof(ITeamExplorer));
```

_currentVsPackage is a Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package; 
ITeamExplorer is of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorer

I am using Visual Studio 2013 RC and Team Foundation Server 2012.

This code works in Visual Studio 2012 and Team Foundation Server 2012!

Comment: You should report this to Microsoft ASAP.

Comment: I reported the problem to Microsoft. Thanks.